# UITable View Do Not Reload

Tags: uitableview

Am using following code in table view for showing last row But here problem is that while using this am unable to scroll the table. I search lot for this but I didn't find the way to solve this question . can anyone give some suggestion how to solve this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

// here to draw cell ImageCell is used for customise cell.

ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; // changed this

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ImageCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease]; // changed this

}
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
// setting the text

NSDictionary *messageData = [messageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[cell setData:messageData];

int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1;
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
// Set up the cell
return cell;
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: what do you mean "cannot scroll the table"? Also, to reload the table, you need to call `reloadData` at some point, which, by with what you provided, is not called.

Comment: yes I am unable to see the upper cell data.Actually am written this code in while drawing table

Comment: "upper cell data" also makes no sense. Either provide more background of your isse or more code.

Comment: This is doing for chat application through web services so when new message comes i have to reload table data I done that and able to show new message but when i want to scroll the table but I unable to do that . Here I can scroll table downward but not upward.

Answer (score 0):

`atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone` is your culprit, use `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom` or `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`

Comment: I also Try this  UITableViewScrollPositionTop  And UITableViewScrollPositionBottom but my problem as it is